# incorrect number of dimensions when using dplyr summarize function

Tags: r, dplyr, na, quantile, percentile

I see an error "incorrect number of dimensions" when I run my code below. 
"mydata" is a data.frame with variables, "depth", "year" and"var".

```
     depth          var year
    75.701  3.314472209 1964
    75.711  6.184566981 1964
    75.721  11.63833113 1964
    75.731  10.92470382 1964
    75.741  6.884034653 1964
    75.751  3.567515285 1964
    75.761  2.07174425  1964
    75.771  2.829011606 1964
    75.781  4.80560514  1964
    75.791  4.18529085  1964
    75.801  3.361608052 1964
    75.811  3.711773806 1964
    75.821  4.059657671 1964
    75.831  7.676827986 1964
    75.841  6.924370206 1963
    75.851  16.98705556 1963
    75.861  21.56234523 1963
    75.871  8.618156376 1963
    75.881  3.487789744 1963
    75.891  2.422058997 1963
    75.901  5.038429763 1963
    75.911  13.29836041 1963
    75.921  20.6988331  1963
    75.931  22.90022852 1963
    75.941  27.97886558 1963
    75.951  50.38703329 1963
    75.961  61.4282796  1963
    75.971  40.49568815 1963
    75.981  23.20749659 1963
    75.991  14.75910651 1963
    76.001  20.02729577 1963
    76.011  36.53041814 1963
    76.021  47.07261365 1963
    76.031  58.02382514 1963
    76.041  55.89395862 1963



library(dplyr)

# I compute percentiles of "depth" every "year". "percrank" is created
mydata.rank<- mydata %>%
group_by(year) %>% 
mutate(percrank=rank(depth)/length(depth))

# Here, I summarize "var" when 0.25<"percrank"<0.75. But I see error.
mydata.rank %>% group_by(year) %>% 
summarize(var=var[which(percrank<=0.75 | percrank>=0.25),])

# error: incorrect number of dimensions

mydata.rank %>% na.omit() %>% group_by(year) %>% 
summarize(var=var[which(percrank<=0.75 | percrank>=0.25),])

# error: incorrect number of dimensions
```

I think, "NA" is problem, but when "na.omit" applied, a same error.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Also, instead of summarize, I need to get quantiles (10th, 25th, 50th, 75th, 90th) of "var" when 0.25<"percrank"<0.75 for every year.

Thanks a lot for your help.

lim

Comment: Try `filter(percrank<=0.75 | percrank>=0.25)` instead of `summarize()`.  You are not summarizing anything, but rather you are subsetting for rows.

Comment: Some similarities with [Calculating quantiles of a variable based on another variable in a given range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495751/calculating-quantiles-of-a-variable-based-on-another-variable-in-a-given-range).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Richard! I tried 'mydata.filter<-mydata.rank %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  filter(percrank<=0.75 | percrank>=0.25)', but it gives the same results of mydata.rank. Is there a problem still in the code?

Comment: Pascal, yes the questions is what I posted.

Comment: Oh, I got it. "|" should be "&", then the filter function works well. THanks a lot!